# Core Plot bar Graph iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I have followed this link http://www.gilthonwe.com/2012/06/09/stacked-bar-chart-coreplot-ios/ and have succeeded in making bar graph what i needed. but now i want something change in this graph i want 2 bar graph lines on single x axis date. i want bar graph like this one.

[image: chart]
<sub>(source: [tqn.com](http://0.tqn.com/d/spreadsheets/1/0/V/1/-/-/bar_graph1.gif))</sub>

but i want 2 bars not 3.

What i have to change or how can i achieve to make this bar graph.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the bar graph I don't think you need the code provided in your link. The easiest way to achieve something like that would be to simple use CALayer to represent the bars in the graph. You just set their frames and backgroundcolors as needed, add them as sublayer to your view and your done (besides creating the axis and labels)

```
CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
layer.frame = /* ... */;
layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

[someView.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use two bar plots, one for each set of bars with the same fill. Use the `barOffset` on each plot to shift one a little bit to the left and the other a little to the right so they join above the bar location. See the Plot Gallery example app for sample code.